# Is it possible to hide source ip?

Tags: webserver, ip-address, isp

In a server log it lists all ip addresses of clients accessing the server. Is it possible for a client to access a server but the server log fail to record this client or ip address of the machine in the server log? For example: a hacker might want to hide its machine address.

I appreciate any information regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: You hide by using a proxy or VPN. There will always be an address recorded.

Comment: If your under ddos attack, the attacked could overwhelm your ability to log, and their address might not get logged.  Depends on your internet connect speed, and the speed of your logging device.

Comment: @seth so if i use a proxy then the recorded ip will be the ip address of the proxy and not my machine. is that correct? that way i can hide my machine even though i can still access the server. is that correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea. Essentially the proxy would be an intermediate party acting on your behalf. The data you're sending might still identify you. The bit about a DOS attack is true as well but would mean that you're not able to access the service any longer.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on what you mean by the "data you're sending might still identify you"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for a client to access a server but the server log fail to record this client or ip address of the machine in the server log?

If an attacker is able to get root/administrative access to a system, he/she can typically delete or even modify logs that are stored on the same system, or reconfigure the webserver software to stop logging or.

For sensitive or attack-prone systems it's smart to configure logs to be sent to a separate, external system.  The most secure but least practical thing to do is send logs to a physical printer.

Leaving absolutely no trace of source IP within a company's network would require access to not only a server but also the intermediate firewall or other perimeter that may be logging traffic, as well as any switches, etc. that may be logging, etc.

Of course, if the target's ISP is logging traffic, that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: so if an attacker cannot be access to the server then there is no way the server fails to record the ip address of the attacker. is that correct?

Comment: There are cases where it might fail but they're usually edge cases. One example is a DOS where the system is so busy doing stuff that it just can't keep up or if you fill up the drive and there is just no more space to record anything. For normal operations, assuming that logging is configured, it usually works.